# Python object creating a group with 3 members of aggregation relationship

Tags: python, class, oop, object, aggregation

I had an assignment to create a python code using class to create a group with 3 members (aggregation relationship). This is my code so far:

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def getInfo(self):
        memberInfo = "Name: " + str(self.name) + "." + "Age: " + str(self.age)
        return memberInfo

class Group:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.memlist = []
    def addMember(self,member):
        self.memlist.append(member)

    def getInfo(self):
        info = "Member List: \n"
        for i in range(len(self.memlist)):
            info += self.memlist[i].getInfo() + "\n"
            print(info)
            break
        
    
mem1 = Member("Chi",20)
mem2 = Member("Bach",7)
mem3 = Member("Gen", 22)

group1 = Group("Siblings")
group1.addMember(mem1)
group1.addMember(mem2)
print(group1.getInfo())
print(mem2.getInfo())
print(group1.memList)
```

But it has shown an error: AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'memList'. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: `memList` (uppercase L) should be `memlist` (lowercase L).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote little function for listing members and their ages.

```
   class member:
       def __init__(self, name, age):
          self.name = name
          self.age = age


       def member_Info(self):
          memberInfo = f"Name: {str(self.name)}-->Age: {str(self.age)}"
          return memberInfo



    class Group:
       def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name
          self.memlist = []


       def addMember(self, name):
          self.memlist.append(name)


       def getInfo(self):
           for i in range(len(self.memlist)):
               info = self.memlist[i].member_Info() + "\n"
               print(info)
```

This all_members function is basically getting the information stored in the member class and return to list. I print using memlist in Group but it didn't work out so I made a new list using all_member function and get information from memlist in group1 with the code that you used for getting information in memlist at group1.getInfo .

```
    def all_members():
        all_mems = []
        for i in range(len(group1.memlist)):
             all_mems.append(group1.memlist[i].member_Info())
        print(all_mems)


    mem1 = member("Chi", "20")
    mem2 = member("Bach", "7")
    mem3 = member("Gen", "22")

    group1 = Group("Siblings")

    group1.addMember(mem1)
    group1.addMember(mem2)
    group1.addMember(mem3)

    print(group1.getInfo())
    print(mem2.member_Info() + "\n")
    print(all_members())
```

I guess this isn't the best answer you can get but I think it will work and also I learn many things while trying to correct it so thank you for posting that.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
print(group1.memList)
```

to

```
print(group1.memlist)
```